# Set the current time for an audio object when a page loads

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

How do I set the current time for an audio object when a html page loads? This is what I am currently doing:

```
var a = document.getElementById("myAudio");

a.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    console.log(this.currentTime);
    // do other stuff like display the current time 
}

var isCurrentTimeSetOnStartup = false;
a.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    if (isCurrentTimeSetOnStartup == false){
        this.currentTime = startTime;
        isCurrentTimeSetOnStartup = true;
    }
});
```

which I think is ugly. If I don't have the isCurrentTimeSetOnStartup guard then the two events trigger each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your script at the bottom of the `<body>` tag and then use the following code to set the [`currentTime`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) of your Audio Source.

---

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#myAudio');
let startTime = 2;


a.addEventListener('canplay', function handler() {
  // Time in seconds
  this.currentTime = startTime; 
  // Remove the event listener
  this.removeEventListener('canplay', handler);
});


a.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  //Time in seconds
  console.log(this.currentTime);
});

// Play on DOM-Load
a.play();
```

```html
<!--http://picosong.com/wwPMj/-->
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</audio>
```

Comment: Can you add a.bind("timeupdate", function() {
    console.log(this.currentTime);
} to your example and see if they trigger each other.

Comment: @Baz Eventually I figured that you cannot use `.bind()` on Audio DOM and I just used `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: Instead of declaring `isFirst` you can do `a.addEventListener('canplay', function canplayListener () { this.currentTime = startTime; this.removeEventListener('canplay', canplayListener); });`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I was in the middle of doing that and then I saw you passed in the handler, and it made sense why mine was bugging :)